# I have a 800px wide website with relative css position - how to scale it for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have a website which which works perfectly on desktop. The site is 800px wide, and it is centered with following css:

```
#example {
    position:absolute; 
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-400px;
    top:0px; 
    width:800px; 
    height:300px;
}
```

Now if I would scale this for mobile devices using something like 'use 100% of device width', would it cause problems that I have defined the centered position also with the `left:50%;`?
Any suggestions how to do the mobile version?

Comment: Get a look on bootstrap, it will help what you are trying to achieve https://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform: translateX(-50%)` instead of `margin-left: -400px`. This will move the (absolutely positioned) element to the left by half of its own width.

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing the following css but it doesn't seem to do what I think it should do.
It even seems like it isn't doing anything.
What could be wrong with it?

In the html I have written
`<div id="div1"><img src=""></div>` .. etc.
so that there are images inside the divs. Could it be that the images don't allow to reduce their dimensions? All the images have the same desktop width 800px.

```
 /* mobile css starts */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 320px) {

  #div1 { 
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-160px;
  top:0px; 
  width:320px; 
  height:91px;
  }

    #div2 {
    background-color:#DFDFDF;
    position:absolute; 
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-160px;
    top: 91px; 
    width:320px; 
    height:72px;
}

#div3 {
    background-color:#DFDFDF;
    position:absolute; 
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-160px;
    top: 163px; 
    width:320px; 
    height:204px;
}

#div4 {
    background-color:#DFDFDF;
    position:absolute; 
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-160px;
    top:367px; 
    width:320px; 
    height:88px;
}

#div5 {
    background-color:#DFDFDF;
    position:absolute; 
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-160px;
    top:455px; 
    width:320px; 
    height:200px;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 540px)  {

  #div1 { 
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-220px;
  top:0px; 
  width:440px; 
  height:125px;
  }

    #div2 {
    background-color:#DFDFDF;
    position:absolute; 
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-220px;
    top: 125px; 
    width:440px; 
    height:100px;
}

#div3 {
    background-color:#DFDFDF;
    position:absolute; 
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-220px;
    top: 225px; 
    width:440px; 
    height:281px;
}

#div5 {
    background-color:#DFDFDF;
    position:absolute; 
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-220px;
    top:506px; 
    width:440px; 
    height:120px;
}

#div6 {
    background-color:#DFDFDF;
    position:absolute; 
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-220px;
    top:626px; 
    width:440px; 
    height:275px;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 799px)  {

  #div1 { 
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-270px;
  top:0px; 
  width:540px; 
  height:153px;
  }

    #div2 {
    background-color:#DFDFDF;
    position:absolute; 
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-270px;
    top: 153px; 
    width:540px; 
    height:122px;
}

#div3 {
    background-color:#DFDFDF;
    position:absolute; 
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-270px;
    top: 275px; 
    width:540px; 
    height:344px;
}

#div4 {
    background-color:#DFDFDF;
    position:absolute; 
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-270px;
    top:619px; 
    width:540px; 
    height:148px;
}

#div5 {
    background-color:#DFDFDF;
    position:absolute; 
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-270px;
    top:767px; 
    width:540px; 
    height:338px;
}
}

/* mobile css end */



body {
    background-color:#DFAFDF;
    height: 1555px;
    width: *;
}

#div1 {
    background-color:#DFDFDF;
    position:absolute; 
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-400px;
    top:0px; 
    width:800px; 
    height:227px;
}

#div2 {
    background-color:#DFDFDF;
    position:absolute; 
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-400px;
    top:227px; 
    width:800px; 
    height:181px;
}

#div3 {
    background-color:#DFDFDF;
    position:absolute; 
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-400px;
    top:408px; 
    width:800px; 
    height:510px;
}

#div4 {
    background-color:#DFDFDF;
    position:absolute; 
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-400px;
    top:918px; 
    width:800px; 
    height:219px;
}

#div5 {
    background-color:#DFDFDF;
    position:absolute; 
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-400px;
    top:219px; 
    width:800px; 
    height:500px;
}
```